# How to identify my telegram channel via my bot

Tags: php, bots, telegram, channel, forward

I use the below method for my bot to delete any forwarded channel post that others send to my group on telegram, but I want the bot not to delete my forwarded channel post.
How can I do it?

```
$forward = $update->message->forward_from_chat;

if ($forward != null) {
    bot('deletemessage', [
        'chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id,
        'message_id' => $update->message->message_id
    ]);
}
```